# Plone vagrant mailer issues

Tags: plone

I'm running Plone 5.0 under vagrant. For some reason the mailer is being blocked and returning ErrNo 111. I've tested on two different machines and I can replicate it on both. The vagrant installer should provide the headless ubuntu a smtp and setup the proper ports.

Error:

```
File "/home/vagrant/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.CMFPlone-5.0-py2.7.egg/Products/CMFPlone/controlpanel/browser/mail.py", line 83, in handle_test_action
    immediate=True)
  File "/home/vagrant/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.MailHost-2.13.2-py2.7.egg/Products/MailHost/MailHost.py", line 237, in send
    self._send(mfrom, mto, messageText, immediate)
  File "/home/vagrant/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.MailHost-2.13.2-py2.7.egg/Products/MailHost/MailHost.py", line 337, in _send
    self._makeMailer().send(mfrom, mto, messageText)
  File "/home/vagrant/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.CMFPlone-5.0-py2.7.egg/Products/CMFPlone/patches/sendmail.py", line 17, in _catch
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.sendmail-3.7.5-py2.7.egg/zope/sendmail/mailer.py", line 46, in send
    connection = self.smtp(self.hostname, str(self.port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 256, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 316, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 291, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

That being said, how do I set this up?

Comment: What do you mean by "the vagrant installer"? plonedev.vagrant does not set up an SMTP agent.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to localhost 25?